# change NSHTTPCookie created time

Tags: ios

So I was manually add one cookie like:

```
-(void)addDomainCookie:(NSString *)domainName {
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.APIBaseURL];
    NSArray *ourCookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:ourURL];
    if (ourCookies.count > 0) {
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [ourCookies firstObject];
        NSDictionary *properties = cookie.properties;
        [properties setValue:@"domain" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
        [properties setValue:domainName forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
        NSHTTPCookie *domainCookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];
        NSMutableArray *mutableCookies = [ourCookies mutableCopy];
        [mutableCookies addObject:domainCookie];

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:[mutableCookies copy] forURL:ourURL mainDocumentURL:nil];
    }

}
```

However, I found the new created cookie's created time is weird:

```
<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"user_id" value:"56377398454919ad5cf642857fa026ce" expiresDate:2018-12-07 10:52:28 +0000 created:2016-02-17 10:52:28 +0000 sessionOnly:FALSE domain:"my.com" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>,
<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"domain" value:"mydomain" expiresDate:2018-12-07 10:52:28 +0000 created:2001-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 sessionOnly:FALSE domain:"my.com" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>
```

The first cookie has created time 2016-02-17 10:52:28 +0000, but when I call `[NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];`, it returns a cookie that created time is 2001-01-01 00:00:01 +0000. What did I miss?

Comment: Are you testing into simulator?

Comment: even on real device, this is still true

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: @girish_pro no, nobody gives answer

Comment: I read NSHTTPCookie reference doc. I think we can't do any thing with create date. Because there is no option to set this.

Comment: But, what is the purpose behind store custom cookie?

Comment: @girish_pro relates to internal testing, use cookie to distinguish